# How to create an object using map function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I want to create an array for my app's dropdown list for age selection. However I dont want to type all ages from 10 till 80. I can create an array with for loop and push methods but I couldn't create format for dropdown list.

You can find below array format below.

```
const ageData = [{ value: 10 }, { value: 11 }, { value: 12 }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map()` as requested:

```js
const ageData = [...Array(71)].map((x, i) => ({value: i + 10}));
console.log(ageData);
```

First, create an array with length `71`. Destructure the array, giving `[undefined, undefined, ..., undefined]`. Then, using `map()`, iterate through the array and return the index, plus 10.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your quick response

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.from()`:

```js
const ageData = Array.from(
    {length: 71}, (_, i) => ({value: i + 10})
);

console.log(ageData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: OP is asking to use `map()` function specifically.

Comment: @Chris `.map()` doesn't operate on blank array or array with undefined values directly. We need to offer other alternatives.

Comment: It does not operate on a blank array, but it does on undefined values. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
const ageData = new Array(70).fill(1).map((_, index) => ({ value: index + 10 }))
```

Also you can create a helper that generates that type of data in a more generic way

```
function generateAgeData (from, to) {
  return new Array(to - from).fill(1).map((_, index) => ({
    value: from + index
  }));
}
```